# MVC | Linq Update Query | Help!

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, controller

I'm making modifications to a C# MVC application that I've inherited.

I have a database, and for simplicity I'll just focus on the two tables I'm working with for this linq query.

**Item**

ItemID Int PK

ItemName

RepairSelection (Yes or No)

RepairID Int FK

**Repair**

RepairID Int PK

RepairCategory

SubmissionDate

DateSentForRepair

Ok, so ItemID is pretty much the identifier, and the View to display the Repair details goes like this (snippet):

```
            <%= Html.LabelFor(x => x.ItemID)%>
            <%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.ItemID)%><br />
            <%= Html.LabelFor(x => x.Repair.RepairCategory)%>
            <%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Repair.RepairCategory, "FormTextShort")%><br />
            <%= Html.LabelFor(x => x.Repair.SubmissionDate)%>
            <%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Repair.SubmissionDate)%><br />
            <%= Html.LabelFor(x => x.Repair.DateSentForRepair)%>
            <%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Repair.DateSentForRepair)%><br />

<%= Html.ActionLink("Edit Repair Details", "Edit", new { ItemID= Model.ItemID})%>
```

Here is the GET Edit action:

```
public ActionResult Edit(Int64? itemId)
        {
            ModelContainer ctn = new ModelContainer();
            var item = from i in ctn.Items where i.ItemID == itemId select i;
            return View(item.First());
        }
```

This is also fine, the GET Edit view displays the right details. Where I'm stuck is the linq query to update the Repair table. I have tried it so many ways today that my head is just fried (new to Linq as you may have guessed). My latest try is here (which I know is way off so go easy ;-) ):

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Int64 itemId, Repair repair, Item item, FormCollection formValues)
        {
            if (formValues["cancelButton"] != null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("View", new { ItemID = itemId });
            }

            ModelContainer ctn = new ModelContainer();

            Repair existingData = ctn.Repair.First(a => a.RepairId == item.RepairID && item.ItemID == itemId);

            existingData.SentForConversion = DateTime.Parse(formValues["SentForConversion"]);

            ctn.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("View", new { ItemID = itemId });
        }
```

For the above attempt I get a Sequence Contains No Elements error.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the issue myself. I just tool a different approach. When I now click on the edit actionlink, I carry over the repairID as opposed to the itemID, and just edit the repair entry directly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like for the repairID in Items table the corresponding rows in Repair table are missing,

Check for the data using the following query:

```
SELECT RepairID FROM Items
EXCEPT
SELECT RepairID FROM Repair
```

This will list you all the missing repairID in Repair table.

If that the case data needs to be corrected or you need use **FirstOrDefault** and check for return value nullability i.e:

```
Repair existingData = ctn.Repair.FirstOrDefault(a => a.RepairId == item.RepairID && item.ItemID == itemId);

    if( existingData!= null)
    {
       existingData.SentForConversion = DateTime.Parse(formValues["SentForConversion"]);
       ctn.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have just updated my question. I should have mentioned that in the Item table, I have a column 'RepairSelection' which is either Yes or No. This gets updated to "Yes" when the initial Repair entry is created. I filter my Items list by this condition, so the data is definitely there. I hope this sheds more light on the situation :)

Comment: If the data is indeed there then the next thing to check is the values posted i.e what are the values assigned to the Item parameter of Edit action. Did you check tht?

Comment: Yup, I've debugged through the code. It's picking up the posted value correctly, however the null exception occurs on my Linq query. existingData is null so that's why I think it's a problem with the way I've written the query. What do you think?

Comment: The error "Sequence Contains No Elements" is definitely becuase the filter "a => a.RepairId == item.RepairID && item.ItemID == itemId" is not returning any rows. I ampretty sure the values that are applied to the filter are yielding 0 rows.

Comment: Hmmm. I'll have to take another look at it with a fresh head tomorrow morning. I tried that SQL query also to display the missing RepairID in the Repair table, and there are 0 rows so I'm stumped.